# Rename SQL Server Table in c# solution in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, renaming

I have a quite complex program written in `C#` and `Visual Studio 2010` using a `SQL Server` database.
 I have to change the name of a table in the database but I am not sure which is the best way to do it: changing the name in the `edmx` file is easy but then I would lose all the references in the solution.
 I tried to change the name in `SQL Server Management Studio` but then when I try to "Update Model from database" in the edmx Visual Studio just adds the table with the new name.
Can anybody help me?
I must use `Visual Studio 2010` because both the server where the source files are stored and the DB server belong to one of my customers and I can connect to it via VPN only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alter the table by settings its new namen. And update the EDMX so the new Table will be visible. After you have done that you need to remove the old entity from the EDMX and change all references yourself in code. That is the easiest way. I hope you have Resharper this way you can do the refactoring a lot quicker